# How to vertically center content using Bootstrap v5.2

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/cover/) website vertical centering for my own website but I keep seen my content up to the top of the view port.

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

My code:

[image: My code]

**The snippet:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JorgeEscobar.XYZ</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container py-auto">
      <header class="mb-auto"></header>

      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" class="img-fluid border border-primary rounded-circle mx-auto d-block" alt="Jorge Escobar's portrait picture">
        </div>
        <div class="col align-self-center">
          <h1 class="text-center">Hola, soy <span class="text-primary">Jorge.</span></h1>
          <p class="text-center text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam
            perferendis libero itaque accusantium fugiat aperiam, illo natus voluptate!</p>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
            <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CpPR5h1ZhHF2ftQGKEgcYfer5TAuAj33/view?usp=sharing" role="button" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Curriculum Vitae</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="mt-auto text-white-50">
        <p>Cover template for <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/" class="text-white">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo" class="text-white">@mdo</a>.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>



    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not vertically centered because you haven't set the height to the parent (i.e., `row`).

See the snippet below.

```css
.row {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>JorgeEscobar.XYZ</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container py-auto">
    <header class="mb-auto"></header>

    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" class="img-fluid border border-primary rounded-circle mx-auto d-block" alt="Jorge Escobar's portrait picture">
      </div>
      <div class="col align-self-center">
        <h1 class="text-center">Hola, soy <span class="text-primary">Jorge.</span></h1>
        <p class="text-center text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam perferendis libero itaque accusantium fugiat aperiam, illo natus voluptate!</p>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
          <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CpPR5h1ZhHF2ftQGKEgcYfer5TAuAj33/view?usp=sharing" role="button" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Curriculum Vitae</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="mt-auto text-white-50">
      <p>Cover template for <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/" class="text-white">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo" class="text-white">@mdo</a>.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**EDIT**

To reply @Jitender... Yes, but the OP didn't include `header` and `footer` into the code. Therefore, my original answer solves the problem. However, if OP wants to have a `header` and `footer`, then the snippet below is the solution.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="d-flex h-100 text-center text-bg-dark">
  <div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
    <header class="mb-auto">Header</header>
    <main>
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" class="img-fluid border border-primary rounded-circle mx-auto d-block" alt="Jorge Escobar's portrait picture">
        </div>
        <div class="col align-self-center">
          <h1 class="text-center">Hola, soy <span class="text-primary">Jorge.</span></h1>
          <p class="text-center text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam perferendis libero itaque accusantium fugiat aperiam, illo natus voluptate!</p>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
            <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CpPR5h1ZhHF2ftQGKEgcYfer5TAuAj33/view?usp=sharing" role="button" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Curriculum Vitae</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="mt-auto">Footer</footer>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given above by Cerves is partially correct... If you are planning to replicate the view in the link provided... You can add a few stlyling like provided below

Like we should add the height to the whole body and have an `overflow-y:hidden`... this will not show scroll and limit you page view to the screen height... The container containing the content here "row" will be set to max-height of 100vh`(height:100vh)`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>JorgeEscobar.XYZ</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </head>
  <body style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: hidden">
  <div class="container py-auto">
  <header class="mb-auto"></header> 
  <div class="row align-items-center" style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: hidden" >
  <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" class="img-fluid border border-primary rounded-circle mx-auto d-block" alt="Jorge Escobar's portrait picture" />
   </div>
   <div class="col align-self-center">
      <h1 class="text-center">
        Hola, soy <span class="text-primary">Jorge.</span>
      </h1>
      <p class="text-center text-muted">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam
        perferendis libero itaque accusantium fugiat aperiam, illo natus
        voluptate!
      </p>
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CpPR5h1ZhHF2ftQGKEgcYfer5TAuAj33/view?usp=sharing" role="button" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Curriculum Vitae</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="mt-auto text-white-50">
    <p>
      Cover template for
      <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/" class="text-white">Bootstrap</a>,
      by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo" class="text-white">@mdo</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I already acomplished this by understanding how 'container-flex' class works in Bootstrap. When first learned Bootstrap, flex containers weren't a thing.